# doubling the scrollbars - one pair working one is like painted c#

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I have problem with vscrollbar and hscrollbar. I want to add them into a panel in windows form. But when i did that, they didnt work. After maximize the window (in debug mode) they get doubled. Two new bars are working fine, but two old bars arent. The old bars stays in the centre of window and looks as they were painted, the new bars are in good position (right and bottom). I don't why their doubled.

Comment: The panel has built in scrollbars.  Just set the AutoScrollMinSize to the size of the canvas that you want to work with.

Comment: If you edit your question with some more detail about what you are trying to do, the community can help you.  As it stands, it's unclear why you are adding these extra scrollbars to a panel.

Comment: ok i give link to other topic, it's should give you more details, what is my goal.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498206/c-sharp-drawing-on-the-panel-and-scrolling-the-result thx for this words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a good design practice, try to limit the number of scroll-bars on the page. Use the standard ones on windows form (you call them "old"), so they will not be "doubled"